# Как отключить растягивание виджетов в PyQt6?

Tags: python, qlayout, pyqt6, qsizepolicy

Я хочу, чтобы при изменении размера окна виджет `QSpinBox` не растягивался по горизонтали.
Я пытался использовать `QtWidgets.QSizePolicy`, но не нашёл достаточно информации по этому поводу.

Решить это через `setFixedSize()` не получается, т. к. если получить значение размера окна `self.size()`, то передаётся значение больше, чем на самом деле

Возможно требуется что-то из настроек самого `QVBoxLayout`

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QCheckBox, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QSpinBox


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.chkbx = QCheckBox('Чекбокс')
        self.text = QLabel('Текст')
        self.numb = QSpinBox()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.totalSizeHint()
        layout.addWidget(self.chkbx)
        layout.addWidget(self.text)
        layout.addWidget(self.numb)
        self.setLayout(layout)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = App()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: `QSizePolicy::Fixed` https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понимаю почему вас не устраивает:

> void QWidget::[**setFixedWidth**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedWidth)(int **`w`**)
>
> Устанавливает минимальную и максимальную ширину виджета в **`w`** без изменения высоты.

```
import sys
'''
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QCheckBox, QWidget, \
    QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QSpinBox
'''
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QCheckBox, QWidget, \
    QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QSpinBox


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.chkbx = QCheckBox('Чекбокс')
        self.text = QLabel('Текст')
        self.numb = QSpinBox()
        
        self.numb.setFixedWidth(35)                          # <----

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
# ???        layout.totalSizeHint()
        layout.addWidget(self.chkbx) 
        layout.addWidget(self.text) 
        layout.addWidget(self.numb) 
        self.setLayout(layout)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = App()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Меня устраивает данный способ, просто я не знал о его существовании

Comment: @Sonter что не так в моем варианте?

Comment: @Sonter Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: В вашем варианте всё хорошо, просто я не искал в этом направлении (использование методов объекта, отличных от `QtWidgets.QSizePolicy`)